# jquery-ui-tabs content interferance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I am using jquery-ui-tabs to allow users to create their own tabs, then ofcourse switch between tabs as they see fit.  The content in the widgets are small widgets which are like mini programs in their own right.  Users can then choose which widgets they want on any given tab.

This works fine as long as any given widget is only set in 1 tab, however, things start going wrong when any given widget is added to 2 tabs or more.  When the widgets are generated, they use the id from the database.  For example .  If a given widget is added to 2 or more tabs, they end up with 2 divs with the id same id, for example widget_1, which causes problems as you can imagine.

So my question is, what is the best way to solve such a problem?

I wish I knew earlier that they wanted to be able to use the same widget on more than 1 tab.  I get the feeling this is almost going to have to be a complete rewrite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does the "div called div1" have "div1" as *class* or *id*?

your question sounds like it's an *id*, and thats all the problem: [the id has to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

to solve this, work with classes - they can be used multiple times and you should be able to do the exact same things (but thats a bit hard to say without seeing some code).

**EDIT:** changed my fist link to show the w3c-recommendation. i linked [this article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm) before

Comment: just using the last line of that article *If you want your Web pages to validate as XHTML or HTML, then you should have unique IDs on your pages.* - Everything works fine without even being validate! I still don't get why people rely so much in recommendation docs... Recommendations exits to follow through, but there are cases here and there that we can't simply follow the recommendations, and let me assure that all still works great... **in any browser!**

Comment: i agree with you, but in this is not the case where we "can't simply follow the recommendations" - this is easy, and if you can choose to follow the recommendation or to break with it, why should anyone choose to break it...

Answer (score -2):

It's not a recommended practice to have the same `id` in the same page, but you should not have problems with it at all, all you need to do in your javascript calls is append the tab it self, for example:

`$(".tab-1 #div1")...` instead of only `$("#div1")...`

though, I would always avoid having the same `id` and "tell" your generator to use `div1-random-number` and always use the class to get the widget using the currently tab as seen in the code above

> [**Live example** on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ejafuz/2/edit#preview)

Comment: i wouldn't recommend to use the same id twice, even if browsers accept that. it's still plain wrong and against the definition: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: **W3 is only a recommendation thingy**, stop thinking that the hole web world will hang if you don't follow a recommendation!

Comment: **Recommendations are there for a reason**, stop thinking that everyone uses a modern bling-bling-browser - there are still people using IE6, Netscape, special Screenreader-Browsers and a lot of other crazy/old stuff wich might _have_ a problem with multiple same IDs. (and it's the same work to use an id or a class. so why should anyone break up with the recommendation without having advanages? at best, nothing happens, but you _might_ get a bunch of probolems)

Comment: you're not. lets stop this discussion here and let the other users vote for the best answer.

Comment: I do business apps for intranets, and there's where the problem arises, not that all users have modern browsers, IE7 and 8!!! doesn't even know what W3 is! I do web app for IE6, every single day! and If I have to follow the w3 recommendations, I was screwed... big time! So, they exist for one and simple reason, to have something to start on, **NOT** to strictly follow it! I'm asking you, **STOP** being so square/kid and listen the olders and the wisers...

Comment: doing dumb things on a large scale and for a long time doesn't make them more correct. the same applies to shouting at / being unfriendly to people. please stop using all those multiple exclamation marks, capslock and bold letters. i'm not too dumb to read or to understand you, i'm just of a different opinion.